# Is there a way to move multiple tabs to a new browser window, in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I know this may seem like a silly question but it is certainly a minor feature that I would love to use, if it exists.  Is there a way to quickly select multiple browser-tabs in Chrome, and move them all to a new browser window?

I know that you can take one tab, and pull it off of the current Chrome session to create  new window. Then, you can drag-and-drop other tabs from any Chrome session to the new window.

At times, I'll often have 20+ tabs open in a browser.  To cut down on clutter, I'll create a new Chrome window and move 3-5 page to the new session.  Currently, this means that I have to drag-drop... drag-drop... drag-drop... and so on.

It would be nice to be able to select the tabs I want to move and just pull them all off at once.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This feature is currently supported like this:

1. Select the first tab
2. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
3. Click on additional tabs you wish to move.
4. Release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
5. Drag the tabs to a new window or outside of the current window and a new window will automatically be created.

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Mac.

Comment: You can also select ranges of tabs with `Shift`.

Comment: Sadly, Firefox doesn't seem to yet.  Very rarely do I do this - but it would be a nice feature for that *sometimes*.  +1, great tips.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot.  I actually tried this, but since my tabs didn't appear to be highlighted, I assumed it wasn't working.  Oh well. You already have 4 up-votes, I have 2 and someone commented that this "isn't possible".  I guess this is a more common (failure of) observation than I would have initially thought.

Comment: @RLH actually, tabs are slightly highlighted (at least in the default theme). Second tab is selected and fourth is active [on this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/NQhxBHv.png).

Comment: I see.  Yes, I've been using a darker-blue theme for years.  I guess that's the problem.

Comment: Note that this does not work in Chrome for Mac.

Comment: @cdeszaq Just use  ⌘ instaed of Ctrl

Comment: @tig Yes, Chrome for Mac has been updated since I left my comment almost 2 years ago. Thanks for pointing out that it works now :-)

Comment: @nerdwaller Firefox does support the that, too!

Comment: I also can't see it visually. GTK theme under Xubuntu. Would have done it with the above instruction instinctively, but didn't see that it was working. The only difference was that the word "tab" in the context menu got replaced by "tabs"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGhFO.png

Answer (score 6):

You can also select tabs by domain/by opener by enabling experimental feature on

chrome://flags/#tab-groups-context-menu

this adds these options on the context menu when right clicking the tab

Comment: (Sadly) this option seems to have been removed

Answer (score 2):

**Windows**
**<kbd>Shift</kbd>** select all tabs in range
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** select multiple tabs

**Mac**
**<kbd>Shift</kbd>** select all tabs in range
**<kbd>⌘</kbd>** select multiple tabs