# How to move multiple Chrome tabs to a new window

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser-tabs

I'd like to be able to move multiple tabs to a new window, so that I can separate groups of tabs from each other. After a precursory Google search [I saw this](https://superuser.com/questions/641405/is-there-a-way-to-move-multiple-tabs-to-a-new-browser-window-in-chrome) on superuser. Unfortunately, none of the methods work for me as I'm on a Mac. Even the experimental flag seems to be gone `chrome://flags/#tab-groups-context-menu`...

*How can I access this functionality as a Mac user in 2017?* I'd prefer to do things the easiest way. If it's installing an extension, or doing a hack. Whatever's clever is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The method shown in post you mentioned works for me exactly as described on a Mac. Make sure to use ⌘-click, not ctrl-click.

Comment: Worked. Just got confused when tabs were only showing as the current one selected at a time (using the `⌘`-click method). But when I dragged it out it appeared as the tabs I selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This question was sort of "answered" in the comments, but to get it answered properly the correct steps to move multiple tabs in Chrome are:

**1)** Click on the first tab

**2A)** Hold SHIFT and click on another tab; that tab and all tabs in between will be selected (but for some odd reason Google has made it so that there is no visible indication)

**(or)**

**2B)** Hold down CTRL and click each extra tab you want to add individually (again they will be selected but they won't look like they are)

**(or)**

**2C)** On Mac computers you may need to use the `⌘` key instead of the CTRL key.

**3)** Drag the original tab (or any of them, I'd imagine) to wherever you want it to go.  All of the other tabs that you selected by CTRL/SHIFT-clicking will move with it.

Comment: Point 3) does not work for me as explained in the answer. When I drag - only the clicked tab will move, leaving the rest of selected tabs where they were. MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, Chrome 67.0.3396.99.

Comment: I just tested it with my Chrome, on that exact version ( 67.0.3396.99), but on Linux, and it still works for me.  I think maybe on Macs you might need to use that weird Mac-only key instead of CTRL (as per cody.codes comment above)?  I've edited my answer to note that.

Comment: Yes, I used CMD key. The only way I figured out how to do it is if I first detach selected tabs to a separate window and then merge them back in with the source window. Which is effective but definitely not intuitive or expected behaviour.

Comment: This was truly helpful. Also helpful was that you mentioned the fact about there being no visual indication. It's 2019 and there's still no visual cues. How stupid of Chrome! Anyway, thanks for the awesome tip!